# Clear a Page on Submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm fairly new to playing with Google scripts and I've done ok except for one issue that I cannot find an answer to no matter where I look.  I have a submit button that on clicking the handler hides the current panel and shows a verticalPanel which has had quite a few labels added to it.

I then have a back button that takes you back to the original panel, so it hides the current and then re-shows the first page.  The problem comes about when they click submit again, I've cleared the verticalPanel, but when adding a new one and adding the content to it the new content begins where the last panel finished off, so 3/4 of the way down the page.  How do I either reuse the existing verticalPanel or dispose of it to add new content??

#### Code

This is an extremely simplified version, oviously you wouldn't write it this way but it helps explain it. Running this code will keep adding the same label every time you click the button, I want a fresh page every time it's clicked:

```
// Script-as-app template. 
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button); 
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler'); 
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked');
  app.add(label)
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

#### Demo

See a demonstration [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxzsWxScFKBnUV4Zg98cYAJ1w5a0sWD180UWtBD8qeUDoAmelxS/exec).

Comment: Please show some code and/or (links to) screen shots, to help explain the situation clearer. If you have a minimal script that exhibits the issue, that would really help.

Comment: This is an extremely simplified version, oviously you wouldn't write it this way but it helps explain it.  Running this code will keep adding the same label every time you click the button, I want a fresh page every time it's clicked:

Comment: // Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var button = app.createButton('Click Me');
  app.add(button);


  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.createLabel('The button was clicked');
  app.add(label)
 
    app.close();
  return app;
}

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxzsWxScFKBnUV4Zg98cYAJ1w5a0sWD180UWtBD8qeUDoAmelxS/exec

Answer (score 0):

In your 'simplified' code, there is no vertical panel. You are directly adding labels to your UIApp. If you have a vertical panel, you can use `VerticalPanel.clear()` to clear it of all existing items

Comment: Yeh, I was doing a simplified version to show the point.  If I use a verticalpanel and clear, it clears but the next click the panel starts where the old one left off so it keeps moving down the page.  In this simple version it's not a big deal, but when you have a panel with a full page of text it really blows it out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure it out, adding the panel in the load segment allowed it to clear properly.  When it is first declared in the onclick function it causes it to do the above behaviour, so by just declaring it in the load and hiding it, then showing it when I need it stops that behaviour.

Not entirely sure why I can't first declare it in the onclick, but it works so I'm not complaining.

Thanks everyone for your help.